# Winforms Transformation

Tags: c#, winforms

The current application am developing has lot of drawings. The Origin of the drawing start from  **Left,Bottom**  instead of **Top,Left**. Drawings works perfectly except "**DrawingString**".

```
Graphics g;  
g.TranslateTransform(0, Height);  
g.ScaleTransform(1, -1);

//All drawings  

g.DrawString("1", new Font("Segoei UI", 9), Brushes.Green, new Point(x, y));
```

The result I get is **upside down** Text [![enter image description here][1]][1] 
**I wanted to draw only the text normal** and rest of the drawings should always start from the bottom left?

**EDIT**

```
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender,PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var g = e.Graphics;
        var height = panel1.Height;
        g.TranslateTransform(0,height);
        g.ScaleTransform(1,-1);
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Black,1),new Rectangle(10,10,100,100));
        g.DrawString("Test",new Font("Segoei UI",9),Brushes.Green,new Point(10,110));
    }
```

**RESULT**
[image]

I want only the text to be flipped. Keeping the drawing as it is

Comment: Is the vertical flip (`ScaleTransform(1,-1)`) the cause of your problem or the attempted fix?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Yes thats making the problem. I tried to compansate by applying a local transformation but it doesnt work

Comment: Can you include enough of your code to make it a [mcve]? As it is now the result is exactly what I would expect.

Comment: So, you want to flip everything else ("lot of drawing"), but leave the text unflipped, am I correct?. This might be possible, but I think it'd be easier and more robust to recalculate all of the coordinates to the top-left system.

Comment: @defaultlocale exactly.

Comment: @defaultlocale I am working in parellel with a very old system which perform the drawing in this fashion and save the data in this way. I cannot change those things

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I only wanted to flip back the text without flipping the drawing.

Comment: The transformation should be X → X and Y→Height - Y

Comment: @N.J As mentioned before, your current code doesn't show that. Include a [mcve] and maybe we can help.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I you have asked i added a simple example . If thats not enough please let me know.

Comment: Down voter could atleast tell why

Comment: @N.J Hm.... you said you *"tried to compansate by applying a local transformation"* but I only see a single transformation being applied. Have you tried applying a *second* transformation to compensate for the previous one?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer yes i tries but since it didnt work i ommited that from the code

Comment: @N.J In that case I'd go with Reza's approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flip it over again.

See the example below. The text **Sunday** appears normally. Then we transpose the graphics object's matrix and write **Monday**, so Monday appears laterally inverted on the Y-axis, and finally we flip over the Y-axis yet again so it restores itself to its original state before writing **Tuesday**, which appears normally.

[image]

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var graphics = e.Graphics; // this.CreateGraphics();
    var font = new Font("Georgia", 12.0F);
    var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    var pointF = new PointF(20F, 20F);
    graphics.DrawString("Sunday", font, brush, pointF);

    graphics.ScaleTransform(1F, -1F);
    pointF = new PointF(10F, -210F);
    graphics.DrawString("Monday", font, brush, pointF);

    graphics.ScaleTransform(1, -1);
    pointF = new PointF(200F, 200F);
    graphics.DrawString("Tuesday", font, brush, pointF);

    brush.Dispose();
    font.Dispose();
}
```

Do that in your code, making sure to calculate the value of the Y-axis where you want your text to appear.

```
g.ScaleTransform(1,-1);
g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Black,1),new Rectangle(10,10,100,100));

g.ScaleTransform(1,-1);
g.DrawString("Test",new Font("Segoei UI",9),Brushes.Green,new Point(10, -110));
```

Comment: Thank you Small change to the code you have provided works perfectly

Comment: Do not use CreateGraphics !

Comment: @TAW, yes, if he's in the `Paint` event he could just get the graphics object from the event args. I'll change my code as well.